Having problems with dynamic rendering in Next.js

// src/app/Cart/page.js

import "@/app/globals.css";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import Cart from "./Cart";

export default async function CartPage() {

    async function getCart () {
        console.log("hoko 2");
        const cookieStore = cookies();
        const token = cookieStore.get('token')?.value;
        try {
            if (token) {
                const { email } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

                const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/getCart`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
                    cache: 'no-store'
                });

                if (res.ok) { // not checking for empty cartlist
                    const data = await res.json();
                    return data;
                } else {
                    console.log("Something went wrong in /api/getCart"); // show the error
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Not Authenticated");
                return [];
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Invalid Token"); //log them out
        }
    }
    const cartItems = await getCart(); 

    return (
       <>
        <Cart InitialCartItems={cartItems}/>
       </>
    )
}

Above is my dynamically rendered route and i expect the console.log("hoko 2"); happen everytime user goes from home to cart page but the log only happens in firstload and browser refreshes which does not make any sense as this is a dynamically rendered route and it should always request to server when page changes right? also home to cart or cart to home is a client-side navigation by using the <Link>
component from next/link and i don't think it to be causing any issues.

I guess i worked my way through the issue, i removed the <Link> component which was covering my cart div in my navigation bar and instead i am now using the useRouter() hook for navigating to my Cart. I firstly defined a function like this.
function handleClick(e, path) {
  e.preventDefault();
  router.push(path);
  router.refresh();   
}

Then pass it to the onClick of my cart div
<div onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "/Cart")}>
   <PiShoppingCartDuotone className="nav_link_icon" />
   <h1 className={pathname === '/Cart' ? "highlight" : ""}>Cart</h1>
</div>

Now it refreshes the data everytime i navigate to my Cart also it will not take a full page reload while doing that.
